# webpack devServer configuration : "‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, webpack, webix

Hi all i'm new in stackoverflow and Premise that i not expert in NodeJs;

below what i have done

I downloaded webix jet from https://github.com/webix-hub/jet-start
unpacked and installed webix jet in Ibm i (As400) via npm install (in Ibm i we run NodeJs V6.9.1)
As Dependencies of webix Jet, there is webpack i think that in installing step also webpack has been installed.
Now if in the Webix Jet app i try to call a web service that run in another domain different from where run Webix Jet, i receive the error :
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://dom.com:10003/jsondemo/wcont.pgm. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
i looked for this error and the workaround seems to enable the server to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
i tried to insert in the webpack.config.js file
this lines in black .. but the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked, remains
can some can help me to solve this problem ?

thanks in advance

here my complete webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
```

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function(env) {

```
var pack = require("./package.json");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var production = !!(env && env.production === "true");
var babelSettings = {
    extends: path.join(__dirname, '/.babelrc')
};

var config = {
    entry: "./sources/myapp.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "codebase"),
        publicPath:"/codebase/",
        filename: "myapp.js"
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader?" + JSON.stringify(babelSettings)
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=25000"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(less|css)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!less-loader")
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
        modules: ["./sources", "node_modules"],
        alias:{
            "jet-views":path.resolve(__dirname, "sources/views"),
            "jet-locales":path.resolve(__dirname, "sources/locales")
        }
    },

    devServer: {
          headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' //just in case
          }
      }, 

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./myapp.css"),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            VERSION: `"${pack.version}"`,
            APPNAME: `"${pack.name}"`,
            PRODUCTION : production
        })
    ]



};

if (production) {
    config.plugins.push(
        new  webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/
        })
    );
}

console.log('Config--> ' ,  config);

return config;
```

}

Comment: Webpack is probably not the cause of your problem. Webpack is a tool to compile and process HTML and Javascript. For your CORS issue you need to be looking at how and where you are making requests.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply ; is it possible to check if the server is created/started with that propoerties  (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) ?? thanks

Comment: I Git cloned the web jet repro you reference and everything seems to work as normal. Can you screen shot your error, and mention in your post how you make the request that gets the error? By the way this repro uses web-pack-dev server, which is a server that serves the bundled JS and HTML from memory, not from a file system.

Comment: Did you try setting the host option of the dev server config? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-host